# Fetch content of google scholar page with php

Tags: php, web-scraping

This is my journal page in Google Scholar:
https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=F4z6guYAAAAJ

I can check the page with browser. But can not get contents by PHP (Curl or File_get_contents)

### I tried many headers but was not useful.

Update :  My code is here:

```
$fgc_context = stream_context_create(array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",                
    'header'=>"Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml\r\n" .
              "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8\r\n" .
              "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\r\n" .
              "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n",
    "timeout" => 60,
    'user_agent'=>"user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.9) Gecko/20071025 Firefox/2.0.0.9\r\n"   
 )
)); 

ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.9) Gecko/20071025 Firefox/2.0.0.9');
$wcnt = @file_get_contents($the_journal_url, false, $fgc_context);
```

And google return a page ends with:

```
<H1>Server Error</H1> We're sorry but it appears that there has been an internal server error while processing your request. Our engineers have been notified and are working to resolve the issue.<p>Please try again later.</p>
```

Comment: What's happening instead?

Comment: Not that I understand your question, because it's terribly formed and includes no details or errors, but try setting a user agent before doing your curl or file_get_contents request- many hosts block requests without user agents.

Comment: Could you share some code and information on errors or what you get returned?

Comment: You should update with your code and the issue/error you are encountering. I'm getting `We're sorry but it appears that there has been an internal server error while processing your request. Our engineers have been notified and are working to resolve the issue.` when trying.

Comment: Maybe microsoft's version with an API would be better for you; http://academic.research.microsoft.com/about/Microsoft%20Academic%20Search%20API%20User%20Manual.pdf. Another thread; https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2567/api-eula-and-scraping-for-google-scholar

Comment: What is that 'user_agent' mess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code :
(run it 2 times to create the cookie the first time)

```
$cookie = __DIR__ . '/cookie.txt';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=F4z6guYAAAAJ');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $data;
```